# Loop in a .bat file with different parameters

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I have a .bat file which renders SSRS reports in PDF format. The report accepts 2 parameters studentID and SubjectID. This runs fine when I try to pass in each studentID and SubjectID.

I would like the .bat file to execute a stored procedure which has list of studentID and SubjectID and run/loop through for each StudentID and SubjectID.
Below is the .bat file code.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
Set varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer

sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_Studentlist" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName 

LOOP:

rs -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v studentid="36" -v subjectid="500" -v vOutputFilePath="C:\ReportRender\Output\ZYZReport.pdf"  -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900 


pause
exit
```

How can i loop through the "rs" Command for each results of the stored procedure

```
dbo.Storedproc_Studentlist
```

This stored proc returns

```
SELECT '1' AS RowNumber,'1789' StudentID, '364' SubjectID, 'C:\Reports\tmurray' OutputLocation
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS RowNumber,'1789' StudentID, '365' SubjectID, 'C:\Reports\tmurray' OutputLocation
UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS RowNumber,'1780' StudentID, '364' SubjectID, 'C:\Reports\mdbrisbin' OutputLocation
```

Thanks,

Comment: Using a .bat file is typically not easy to maintain. An alternate approach would be to use a data-driven subscription. The stored procedure can supply the parameter values and the report can be emailed or stored in a shared folder.

Comment: Using standard edition, cannot use data-driven subscription :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command **FOR** can be used to run a command in a loop from within a batch file.

Here is one possible solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "ListFile=%TEMP%\StudentList.tmp"
set "varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer"

if exist "%ListFile%" del "%ListFile%"
sqlcmd.exe -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_Studentlist" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName >"%ListFile%" 2>nul
if exist "%ListFile%" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=5,7 delims=', " %%A in ("%ListFile%") do (
        echo Processing student with id %%A and subject with id %%B ...
        rs.exe -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v studentid="%%A" -v subjectid="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="C:\ReportRender\Output\ZYZReport.pdf" -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900
    )
    del "%ListFile%"
)

endlocal
pause
```

It might also work to process the output of `sqlcmd.exe` directly without using a temporary list file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer"

for /F "tokens=5,7 delims=', " %%A in ('sqlcmd.exe -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_Studentlist" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName 2^>nul') do (
    echo Processing student with id %%A and subject with id %%B ...
    rs.exe -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v studentid="%%A" -v subjectid="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="C:\ReportRender\Output\ZYZReport.pdf" -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900
)

endlocal
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `del /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `exit /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>` and `2>nul`.

The redirection operator `>` within `2>nul` within command **FOR** in second batch code must be escaped with `^` to be applied on execution of `sqlcmd.exe` and not interpreted as redirection operator for command **FOR** at an invalid position in the command line resulting in a syntax error on execution of the batch file without `^`.